# How to pause the timer in c#?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a timer in my code with a 10s interval.

When the time elapses I will do some checking. It may takes more than 10s for checking and some update jobs.

However, if I didn't stop the timer, it seems the checking will execute every 10s. If I call `stop()`, the timer cannot be started again.
i.e. something like:

```
    protected void timer_elapsed(object sender, EventArgs args) 
    {
        __timer.Stop();
        //Some checking here more than 10s
        __timer.Start();
    }
```

I just want another 10s to check again before the checking is done.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe try setting the timer enabled property to false when you don't want it to run, the set it back to enabled when you're ready to go again.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that is something like winforms or WPF, that *should* work. Are you sure you aren't getting an exception or something?

If it is web, all bets are off ;-p You should perhaps clarify if this is `System.Threading.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, or something else.